# WIX CustomAction.CA.dll not working in Windows XP machine

Tags: wix, windows-xp, wix3.5, wix3.6

Can anyone know why WIX Customaction.dll not working with Windows XP with service pack 3?As i developed my .msi with Wix setup in Windows 8 machine with VS 2010 environment.And this is working fine and is calling my customaction.CA.dll.Where as when i tried to test the same msi in windows XP machine this not working? do i need to do any changes in the customAction.dll so that it will work in XP machine also?Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be used .NET Framework 4.0 (CLR 4.0) in your custom action. It will not run in .NET Framework 4.0 or newer is not installed machine.

In your XP machine .NET Framework 4.0 may not be installed. So that you’re custom action is not running.

Use [useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx34a2h.aspx) property in your `CustomAction.Config` file and set all supported time version which you want to use (CLR 2.0 for .Net Framework 2.0 and 3.5, CLR 4.0 for .Net Framework 4.0 and 4.5)

Comment: thanks for valuable input, based on your comments i installed framework 4.0 in the Windows XP machine and also i added the supported version in the CustomAction.config file and after that my CustomAction started working.

Comment: can you tell me how to check whether my CustomAction.CA.dll is calling or not because i am showing one dialog UI to my user can i able to check whether my CustomAction is calling or not otherwise i can show a message??

Comment: @reapen Run msiexec with logging. It will note the beginning and end of your custom action. If you need more detail, add Windows Installer logging calls to your custom action code.